# Fix needed to syntax bypass native cmd limitation[multilineEcho]OR able to pipeout multivalues from a"IN (...)"clause OR another option to printtofile

Tags: windows, cmd, file-io, pipe, echo

I'm facing an issue while dealing with this syntax:

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\any-video.avi" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1 | FOR /F "tokens=8" %f in ('findstr "silence_duration:"') do @echo %f >>"C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\TEMP.txt"
```

As I did had to use Echo to display the output on console to then after be able to printout to the file(otherwise if nothing in place it doesn't printsout), I was also forced to use it as Append(>>),and not(>) that would be ideal for me since I don't want to keep combining different file outputs, Because while Echo is able to print to console with all its outputs when multiple requested strings were found, when using it with(>) printing to file this way will just save to file the last string of multiple strings found and not all;

Then, I need a solution to this syntax be able to bypass the native cmd limitation of multiline Echo to a file with ">" OR another possible way to fully pipeout multiple strings found from a "IN (...)" clause of a "FOR" command OR any other option to print-to-file all the data found in these circuntances without using a batch file.

Comment: Instead of posting code which is absolutely wrong, _(even as your second attempt at this same issue)_, how about you explain the exact task, complete with real data, show us what outputs you want from that data, and where, so that we can assist you. The idea is that we can all reproduce your environment and specific problem. Once we can do that, it's much simpler for us to understand and work through to a solution.

Comment: `(for ... do echo blah)>file`. Note the parentheses.`

Comment: oh, it worked! so simple concatenation and somehow it slipped through me even that I dealt with a lot of concatenate formulas in Excel, thank you kindly @Stephan , just as the other issue where I found someone else that gave me the solution in a split second, the best support indeed aren't the ones giving excuses, but those actually finding/pointing to the answers.
btw, you should post it as an answer for me to mark, may be useful for someone else too, thanks again. ^^

Comment: I edited out the solution, because the question post is the wrong place for that. You could [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question though and even accept your own answer then…

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining aschipfl, I did it, though it says I need to wait until tomorrow to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: [Stephan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) fix on this case:

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\any-video.avi" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1 | (FOR /F "tokens=8" %f in ('findstr "silence_duration:"') do @echo %f) >"C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\TEMP.txt"
```

Thank you. ~